# Flutter access variables in state

Tags: flutter

I want to get variables of a StatefulWidget from within the state. Is there a easy way to just get the Stateobject like `username.state.value`.

EDIT:
To clarify I want to access a variable that's defined in the state from the parent of the widget(not the state). The variable is gonna change, but I don't want to update it constantly in the parent. I want to get the variable when I press a button. I have an example below how I can access variables normally, but I want to know if there is a way to access the state and its variables.

EDIT2: I am getting suggestions that I should use a listener(this.onValueChange), but isn't that inefficient. I only want to get the value once and not every time I change the value.

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? validator;

  const MyTextField(
      {super.key,
      this.validator});

  @override
  State<MyTextField> createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  String value = "";
```

```
MyTextField username = MyTextField(validator: null)
String? validator = username.validator;
String value = ?
```

Comment: where do you want to use that value? there is a way to get that value if you want to use it in its child widget.

Comment: i want to use it within the child(it gets updated with setState()), but also want to access it from outside on a buttonclick

Comment: what is this value? is it text field text?

Comment: its a simplified version of my problem. I have 2 variables that I want to access. One is a bool and the other is the filtered text field text. I thought if i can access a String it should be able to access every other kind of variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit-:**

You can update states with two ways

1. call-backs
2. state management

**Call Backs**

They are very useful but it will get messy when your app grows. You can start by looking into `VoidCallBack` you can create similar function signature with different parameters using `typedef` keyword.

**State Management**

Obviously very useful but more importantly it will keep your business logic out of your UI logic. In real world apps, you will use this and callback use case based.

So I assume you are going to use state management then start by looking into `ChangeNotifier` and `InheritedWidget`, these are flutter inbuilt state management systems. But they can be little hard to understand at first for new commers so start by using `provider` package from pub.dev. Its very easy to use and for 90% of the time you won't need anything else for the state management.

Comment: its the other way around. The variable will be set and updated in the state and I want to access it from outside.

Comment: @frederik I have made an edit please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

One you can do this is you set a function and when ever these value change, call that function:

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? validator;
  final Function(String) onValueChange;

  const MyTextField(
      {super.key,
      this.validator, this.onValueChange});

  @override
  State<MyTextField> createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}
```

Then where ever you define `MyTextField` pass this function and listen to that value:

```
return MyTextField(
   validator: null,
   onValueChange:(value){
     setState((){
       print('value =$value');
     });
   }
);
```

or in your case use it like this:

```
    String _value = '';
    MyTextField username = MyTextField(validator: null, onValueChange:(value){
             setState((){
               _value = value;
             });
           })
```

Comment: isnt that a redundent listener. It needs to keep listening until the value changes. I want to have a single check that triggers when I press a button

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the way you want, I hope some body else could help you.